# How to disable drag selection with middle mouse button?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Go to [kitchensink](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink), using middle button of mouse, try to click and hold the mouse on empty area of canvas and move the mouse.

The selection rectangle is displayed. How to disable this? I ask because, I have middle mouse button click and drag bound to canvas pan in previous version of fabric. Upgrading to new version, the canvas is behaving in unexpected manner.

---

I've tried to disable selection on the canvas on mouse down if the `event.button == 1` by doing `canvas.selectable = false;` in mousedown  and set it to true back in mouseup event handler.

That didn't work.

Any ideas how to disable the selection using middle mouse button click and drag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prasanth, your problem is simple. You have typo. Try to use like this:

```
canvas.selection = false;
```

Here is a code which you can try:

```
canvas.on('mouse:down',function(e){
    canvas.selection = true;
});
canvas.on('mouse:down',function(e){
  if( e.e.button == 1 ) {
    canvas.selection = false;
  };
});
```

Comment: ohhh! i was misled by old documentation, i think. thanks a lot, good observation :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that fabric recently enabled click for other button rather than left.
The point is that left is handled, right is handled, middle is not...
I guess the middle button follow the flow of the left button just because it is not the right one.

here a snippet from the mousedown handler function of fabric as at version 1.7.3 ( current as feb 2017 ).

```
 __onMouseDown: function (e) {

      var target = this.findTarget(e);

  // if right click just fire events
  var isRightClick  = 'which' in e ? e.which === 3 : e.button === 2;
  if (isRightClick) {
    if (this.fireRightClick) {
      this._handleEvent(e, 'down', target ? target : null);
    }
    return;
  }

  ... continue normal flow ...
```

so this require a proper fix.

Posting a custom event as suggested is a patch, but normally this should not happen at all.
(since i m a mantainer for the project i m going to fix this)